# How to solve the recurrence: T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n?

Tags: runtime-analysis, recurrence-relation, recursion

In a an exercise I'm required to analyze the runtime of recursive function:

```
 foo(n)
     for i from 1 to n
         work() // O(1)
         foo(n-1)
     end for
 end foo
```

The recurrence relation I understand from the code is: `T(n) = n*T(n-1) + n`

But I'm failing trying to analyze it using the iterative method since I don't see a repeating pattern when I'm opening some of the terms

How do I solve this recurrence ?

Comment: Up to which precision are you expected to solve it? Can you solve it without the $+n$ term?

Comment: We have collected some useful material [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers), but I think "guess & proof" is what your teachers expect here. Hint: falling factorials.

Comment: @Raphael I guess lower and upper bound (theta), as well as figuring out how many times `work()` will be called as an expression of `n`

Comment: So, asymptotics. Ironically, I think the exact figure (in non-closed form) is easier here than a "nice" asymptotic.

Comment: What's my play here? run some `n`s and look for a pattern of the amount of times `work()` was called ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like 
$$
T(n) = n! + \left(\frac{n!}{0!} +\frac{n!}{1!} +\frac{n!}{2!} +\frac{n!}{3!} + \dots + \frac{n!}{(n-2)!} + \frac{n!}{(n-1)!}\right)
$$
satisfies the recurrent relation (here $T(0) = 1$).

From this for example $T(n) \leq n!(1+e)$.

Comment: And how do they *get* there?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the pattern (aka ["guess and prove"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2799/98)) is definitely a workable approach here. Sometimes it's about arranging things in the right way in your head:

[image]
(Assuming $T(0) = 0$ as anchor.)

This path leads to an exact solution in terms of "well-known" functions, namely a sum of *falling factorials* if not a nice closed form. You'd then prove this guess correct using *induction*, which is elementary here.

---

Actually, there is a mechanical approach to 
solve this: using [generating functions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/3135/98). Since clearly $T(n) \in \Omega(n!)$, we know we'll have to use *exponential* generating functions (at least). So, from the ansatz

$\qquad\displaystyle T(z) = \sum_{n \geq 0} t_n \cdot \frac{z^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq 1} n \cdot \frac{z^n}{n!} + \sum_{n \geq 1} n \cdot t_{n-1} \cdot \frac{z^n}{n!}$

we obtain, using elementary manipulation of sums/series, that

$\qquad\displaystyle T(z) = ze^z \cdot \frac{1}{1-z}$.

Inserting the well known series for $e^z$ and $(1-z)^{-1}$ and applying the *(binomial) convolution*, you get the same solution as "seen" above:

$\qquad\displaystyle t_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.

Now, we can rearrange:

$\qquad\displaystyle t_n \ =\  n! \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} \ =\ n! \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k!} \ \sim\  n! \cdot e$.